# SQL Server related perfmon counter porting 0 on remote machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I'm trying to monitor a remote SQL Server via perfmon but all SQL related counters are reading 0.

What works:

- On the target Windows Server 2008 running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, reading both Server and SQL Server related counters.
- From a remote Windows Server 2008 machine, reading the target SQL Server's Server related perfmon counters (% Processor Time) using Performance Monitor.

What doesn't work:

- From a remote Windows Server 2008 machine, read the target SQL Server's SQL Server related perfmon counters (e.g., Batch Requests/sec).

Is there a permission I missed?